# Adding 'www' to url via .htacess mod_rewrite does not work

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, no-www

Here is the sample found in numerous posts

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yatko.com[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yatko.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

*wanted to rewrite the main domain only leaving the addon/parked domains unaffected
- the sample above does not work for some reason.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "does not work?"

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Yes, the htaccess works fine, all other rules work without issues, this is the only one that doesn't. If I use a general rewrite that adds www that one works as well. Only this solution doesn't that includes the domain itself. I was asking if there is any mistake in my sample?

Answer (score 1):

**updated**
did you set `RewriteEngine On` on top of the .htaccess ? :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^yatko\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yatko.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed that one in my question, yes I have.